# Div hidden by jQuery hide() keeps reappearing

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, show-hide

My application is a message board. When I click on the ans_button, a div appears with the text area for the question. When I submit the question, the message div is once again hidden.  If I click remove_button, that specific message is deleted from the inbox and the remaining messages are still displayed. However, as soon as I click a second rmeove_button, the message div appears, when it is supposed to remain hidden. Lastly, if I refresh the page, I can once again click remove once, but the second time breaks the code.

I have included code the code wherein I think the problem is contained. However, if need be, I can upload more code. Any suggestions as to where my code is getting caught up would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content" id="messageView">
    <!--This content is pulled from a php file-->
        <!--.ans_button and .remove_button are echoed from php-->
</div><!--content#messageView-->
<div class="content" id="message">
    Subject:<input id="subject" type="text"><br><br>
    Question:<textarea id="question"></textarea><br><br>
    <input class="submitbutton" id="cancelQ" type="button" value="Cancel" >
    <input class="submitbutton" id="askQ" type="button" value="Respond" >       
</div><!--content#message-->
```

php:

```
$findMsg = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
            FROM MessageAdmin m, Admin a, User u
            WHERE (SELECT deptID FROM Admin a WHERE a.deptID = m.programID)
            AND (SELECT o.threadID FROM OpenMessages o WHERE o.threadID = m.threadID
            AND o.isClosed = 0 AND (o.answeredBy = 0 OR o.answeredBy = '$curUser')
            AND (u.userID = o.userID) AND (m.userID = o.userID)) ORDER BY m.timeSent");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($findMsg) > 0){
            echo "<table id='viewMsg'>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($findMsg)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['firstName']." ".$row['lastName']."</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['subject']."</td>";
                echo "<td><button class='ans_button' 
                    value='".$row['threadID'].'*'.$row['subject'].'*'.$row['programID']."'>Respond</button></td>";
                echo "<td><button class='remove_button' 
                    value='".$row['threadID'].'*'.$row['timeSent']."'>Delete</button></td>";
                echo "</tr>";       
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        else
            echo "<h3>You currently have no messages</h3>";
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#message").hide();
    var request1 = $.ajax({ //fill content of #messageView
        ...
    }).success(function(data){
        $("#messageView").html(data);
    });

    $('.content').on('click', '.ans_button', function(){
        var clicked = $(this);
        var parts = clicked.val().split("*");
        var thread = parts[0];
        var subject = parts[1];
        var program = parts[2];
        $("#subject").val(subject);

        $("#askQ").on('click', function(){                      
            var question = $("#question").val();
            var request2 = $.ajax({
                ...
            }).success(function(data){
                if(data == "success"){
                    $("#message").hide();
                    $("#question").val("");
                }
            });
        });
    });

    $('.content').on('click', '.remove_button', function(){
        var clicked = $(this);
        var parts = clicked.val().split("*");
        var thread = parts[0];
        var time = parts[1];
        var request3 = $.ajax({
            ...
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data == "success"){
                $("#message").hide();   
                $("html").load("messages.php");
               $("#messageView").show();                    
            }       
        });
    });
}); //end of document.ready
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** There's a lot of "wrong" going on here, buddy.

To start, you have a click function within a click function. I've fixed that.

You also shouldn't be loading `.messages.php` to the `html` tag. Remove the body tags in `messages.php` and apply the load (i.e. `.load()`) to a container selector (as per our private chat and my code below).

To prevent page refresh when the buttons are clicked (which would defeat the purpose of using ajax) you need to prevent the default behaviour of the button and use `return false` to prevent the page from refreshing.

Furthermore, you have the ajax calls as variables (which aren't being called anywhere. Even if they were, it's sloppy.). This is not correct either. I've fixed this.

Finally, I've added code to prevent multiple clicks/submits when the buttons are clicked. Essentially all I'm doing is disabling the button once it clicked and re-enabling it on the ajax success call.

```
$(function(){ 

    $("#message").hide();

    $.ajax({ //fill content of #messageView
        ...
    }).success(function(data){
        $("#messageView").html(data);
    });

    $('.ans_button').on('click', function() {
        var parts = $(this).val().split("*");
        var thread = parts[0];
        var subject = parts[1];
        var program = parts[2];
        $("#subject").val(subject);        

        return false;
    });

    $('#askQ').on('click', function() { 

        // disable button on click
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var question = $("#question").val();
        $.ajax({ 
            ...
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data == "success"){
                $("#message").hide();
                $("#question").val(""); // why is this empty? Try using .reset() instead if you want to empty field

                // enable and remove disable attr
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });

        return false; 
    });

    $('.remove_button').on('click', function() {

        // disable button on click
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var clicked = $(this);
        var parts = clicked.val().split("*");
        var thread = parts[0];
        var time = parts[1];
        $.ajax({
            ...
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data == "success"){
                $("#message").hide(); 

                $(".container").load("messages.php");

                $("#messageView").show();  

                // enable and remove disable attr
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");                  
            }       
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, these are classes, since there may be numerous buttons. This div is populated by php and a mysqli query, so each displayed message has an answer and delete button.

Comment: Where's the HTML for those? You're posting code that applies to HTML you haven't shared. If they do in fact exist, try adding my `return false`'s I added to your jQuery code.

Comment: Also a little worried about this line, `$("html").load("messages.php");`...if you're running a MVC php framework, you should return the new `view` via your controller. Right now you're appending `messages.php` to the HTML tag, which seems wrong. Does `messages.php` have body tags?

Comment: yes it does. It is a full blown html page with php interspersed.

Comment: I see you added php code and those classes are in fact buttons. Did you try the return false's?

Comment: If I return false as you show, then my page does not always refresh.

Comment: If the page refreshes, the DOM resets...making everything in those click functions irrelevant once clicked and initiated anyways. If you're using Ajax, why do you want your page to reload?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41583/discussion-between-gotguts-and-mike-barwick)